# Creating dynamic <div>'s from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, gridview

I'm trying to figure out how I could create new  within container (to create card from each message in JSON) from JSON that I get from server as a response. Problem is, that I haven't got my head around how to do it.

Data I'm getting looks like this:

```
> {
>     "result": [
>         {
>             "context": "",
>             "group": "",
>             "id": "",
>             "message": "#joined Live Feed",
>             "state": "published",
>             "sys_created_by": "system",
>             "sys_created_on": "2017-02-12 18:32:53",
>             "sys_id": "024a205e830330008b410e8761c3e278"
>         },
>         {
>             "context": "",
>             "group": "",
>             "id": "",
>             "message": "Go to Tools -> Protection -> Protect Workbook",
>             "state": "published",
>             "sys_created_by": "mara.rineheart",
>             "sys_created_on": "2017-02-12 18:35:04",
>             "sys_id": "02caa45e830330008b410e8761c3e228"
>         },
>         {
>             "context": "",
>             "group": {
>                 "link": "https://dev49574.service-now.com/api/now/table/live_group_profile/cc4d3b9c834330008b410e8761c3e2e8",
>                 "value": "cc4d3b9c834330008b410e8761c3e2e8"
>             },
>             "id": "",
>             "message": "ITIL User created the group",
>             "state": "published",
>             "sys_created_by": "itil",
>             "sys_created_on": "2017-02-07 04:46:47",
>             "sys_id": "044d3b9c834330008b410e8761c3e2ea"
>         },
>         {
>             "context": "",
>             "group": {
>                 "link": "https://dev49574.service-now.com/api/now/table/live_group_profile/a58c43be838330008b410e8761c3e265",
>                 "value": "a58c43be838330008b410e8761c3e265"
>             },
>             "id": "",
>             "message": "Thanks! The problem is sporadic. AT&T is laying cable outside. Maybe related?",
>             "state": "published",
>             "sys_created_by": "taylor.fogerty",
>             "sys_created_on": "2017-02-19 00:16:08",
>             "sys_id": "10627418831330008b410e8761c3e276"
>         },
>         {
>             "context": "",
>             "group": {
>                 "link": "https://dev49574.service-now.com/api/now/table/live_group_profile/a58c43be838330008b410e8761c3e265",
>                 "value": "a58c43be838330008b410e8761c3e265"
>             },
```

And I would like to get it sorted so that each message would go in one  having information like:

- Name = (who created message)
- Date = when it was created
- Info = Actual message

> "id": "",
>
> > ```
> >         "message": "Thanks! The problem is sporadic. AT&T is laying cable outside. Maybe related?",
> >         "state": "published",
> >         "sys_created_by": "taylor.fogerty",
> >         "sys_created_on": "2017-02-19 00:16:08",
> >         "sys_id": "10627418831330008b410e8761c3e276"
> > ```

[The actual HTML and numbered 's I'm trying to get data into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJGXh.png)

Any ideas how I should tackle this?

EDIT:

So now I'm getting closer, i hope but still cannot understand why I cannot catch any strings from dataset while looping them through.

Here's my JS and HTML: (I removed POSTMAN TOKEN so it even can't work here:)

```js
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;


xhr.open("GET", "https://dev49574.service-now.com/api/now/table/live_message?sysparm_limit=10");
xhr.onload = function() {
  var jsonResponse = xhr.response;
  var jsonResponse = jsonResponse.substr(10);
  JSON.stringify(jsonResponse, null, 4);
  JSON.stringify(jsonResponse, null, "\t");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
      var markup =
        '<div><ul><li>' +
        jsonResponse[i].sys_id + '</li><li>' +
        jsonResponse[i].message +
        '</li></ul></div>';
      $('#container').append(markup);
    }
  })
  console.log(jsonResponse);
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46WjlUNnFaZUIhSCpJ");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", " REMOVED ");

xhr.send(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting then? We need more info on *why* its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your data set and append markup to the DOM. Using jquery:

```js
var results = [
  {
    "context": "",
    "group": "",
    "id": "1",
    "message": "#joined Live Feed",
    "state": "published",
    "sys_created_by": "system",
    "sys_created_on": "2017-02-12 18:32:53",
    "sys_id": "024a205e830330008b410e8761c3e278"
  },
  {
    "context": "",
    "group": "",
    "id": "1",
    "message": "#joined Live Feed",
    "state": "published",
    "sys_created_by": "system",
    "sys_created_on": "2017-02-12 18:32:53",
    "sys_id": "024a205e830330008b410e8761c3e278"
  },
  {
    "context": "",
    "group": "",
    "id": "1",
    "message": "#joined Live Feed",
    "state": "published",
    "sys_created_by": "system",
    "sys_created_on": "2017-02-12 18:32:53",
    "sys_id": "024a205e830330008b410e8761c3e278"
  }

]

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var markup = 
      '<div><ul><li>' + 
      results[i].id + '</li><li>' + 
      results[i].message + 
      '</li></ul></div>';
    $('#container').append(markup);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I almost got this working but I had some issues as the dataset starts:

`> {
>     "result": [
>         {

So I'm getting undefined. If I add data manually your solution works.

Also the dataset is coming from this:

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

So I'm having issues getting data outside from that function so that I could do some trimming for dataset..

Comment: Got around this by:

xhr.open("GET", "https://dev49574.service-now.com/api/now/table/live_message?sysparm_limit=10");
xhr.onload  = function() {
   var jsonResponse = xhr.response;
   // do something with jsonResponse
   console.log(jsonResponse);
};

This is JSON response I'm getting: [https://pastebin.com/HHbk8JyE]

Now I probably should trim first '{' and 'result:' from the dataset to get it to work. There's something weird going on while trying to parse the data received and I'm not getting result similar to solution with dataset from your post.

Comment: @AslakLaine I don't know what your data looks like, but this is a working solution to your problem. Also when giving code examples use `code blocks like this`. It makes it so much more readable. All you need to do is get your data in the way you need it, then loop over it and create dom elements. You can't just copy line for line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using JavaScript:

```
//Main div
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("MainDiv");

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

        var messageBoxDiv = document.createElement("div");

        var NameDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var NameLbl = document.createElement("span");
        MessageLbl.innerHTML = "Name: " + result[i].sys_created_by;
        NameDiv.appendChild(NameLbl);

        var CreatedOnDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var CreatedOnLbl = document.createElement("span");
        MessageLbl.innerHTML = "Date: " + result[i].sys_created_on;
        CreatedOnDiv.appendChild(CreatedOnLbl);

        var MessageDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var MessageLbl = document.createElement("span");
        MessageLbl.innerHTML = "Info: " + result[i].message;
        MessageDiv.appendChild(MessageLbl);

        messageBoxDiv.appendChild(NameDiv);
        messageBoxDiv.appendChild(CreatedOnDiv);
        messageBoxDiv.appendChild(MessageDiv);

        mainDiv.appendChild(messageBoxDiv);

    }
```

Comment: How should my HTML look in this case? Thanks :)

Comment: You would just need to create a div for the MainDiv